# Why does dividing a float by an integer return 0.0?

Tags: java, math, division, integer-division

So if I have a range of numbers '0 - 1024' and I want to bring them into '0 - 255', the maths would dictate to divide the input by the maximum the input will be (1024 in this case) which will give me a number between 0.0 - 1.0. then multiply that by the destination range, (255).

Which is what I want to do!

But for some reason in Java (using Processing) It will always return a value of 0.

The code would be as simple as this

```
float scale;
scale = (n/1024) * 255;
```

But I just get 0.0. I've tried double and int. all to no avail. WHY!?

Comment: `n` must also be defined as `float`.

Comment: n need not be float, only numeric. however 1024 must be float/double (1024.0)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It's because you're doing integer division.

Divide by a double or a float, and it will work:

```
double scale = ( n / 1024.0 ) * 255 ;
```

Or, if you want it as a float,

```
float scale = ( n / 1024.0f ) * 255 ;
```

Answer (score 19):

n / 1024 is *integer division*, which yields an integer (ie. 0 in this case).

Use `n / 1024.0` instead.

Answer (score 7):

I presume `n` is an `int`. Because the constants 1024 and 255 are both `int`s all the right-hand side calculations are being done with integer arithmetic. Meaning the result of `n/1024` is being truncated to a integral value before being multiplied by `255`.

Any of these modifications will make the calculations work correctly:

```
scale = n / 1024.0 * 255.0;       // Use double constants.
scale = (double) n / 1024 * 255;  // Convert n to a double.
scale = n * 255 / 1024;           // Multiply before dividing.
```

The last one uses integer math still but switching the order of operations means you won't get the undesired truncation to 0. You'll still only get integer answers though, so you'll lose any decimal points in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You should auto-cast n to float by means of a multiplication FIRST, otherwise you're doing an integer operation and then casting the result, instead of doing the operation between floats.

```
float scale;
scale = n * 1.0 / 1024 * 255;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case `n/1024` results in 0 as you are doing integer division. To overcome this you can cast `n` to `float`. This will give you a result between `0.0` and `1.0` next you multiply with `255` and cast the result back to integer. Also you need to declare `scale` as `int`

```
int scale;
int n = 80; 
scale = (int)(((float)n/1024) * 255);
```

Answer (score 2):

others have given great answers already. In case you want your scale to be an integer (which makes sense if your n is an integer already), you could do

```
int scale = ((255 * n)/1024);
```

Note that you won't hit any problems with this as long as these are the numbers, since n * 255 will always fit in an int when the maximum n = 1024.

more flexible would be

```
int scale(int value, int old_max, int new_max){
  java.math.BigInteger big_value = java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(value);
  java.math.BigInteger big_old_max = java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(old_max);
  java.math.BigInteger big_new_max = java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(new_max);
  java.math.BigInteger mult = big_value.multiply(big_old_max);
  return (int) mult.devide(big_new_max).doubleValue();
}
```

You won't overflow any ints this way, though I admit this is a bit verbose

Edit:

Basicly the same, but less clunky (though for very high numbers you might run into some precission errors)

```
int scale(int value, int old_max, int new_max){
  double factor = (double) new_max / (double) old_max;
  return factor * value;
}
```

Comment: Heh, this is why I hate BigInteger and BigDecimal.