# Android issue in division and multiplication

Tags: java, math

I am facing an issue in multiplication and division:

```
float value =  (100 / 846) * 500;
Log.i(TAG,"value = " + value);
```

Every time this float value i slogged as `0.0`

What is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [noob: Why divide always produces 0.0 float/integer problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779604/noob-why-divide-always-produces-0-0-float-integer-problem)

Comment: I was only twitting yesterday wondering why people forget primary school maths like integer division and remainder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

100 is not a float, it's an int. Use 100f, 846f and 500f for floats.

Answer (score 4):

100 / 846 is an integer division and yields 0. Use (100.0 / 846.0) * 500.

Answer (score 1):

You're performing integer division and multiplication and storing that result in a float variable. use float literals instead. E.g. 100f

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with:

```
float value =  (100F / 846F) * 500F;   
Log.i("==========","  value == > " + value);
```